# Under WildFly a transaction that is rollback-only does not allow selects. Why?

Tags: transactions, wildfly, wildfly-26

If a non ApplicationException occurs under WildFly the transaction is marked as rollback only (CMTTxInterceptor). Any follow up SQL throws an SQLException (in WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive) because of this state. But handling an exception may involve getting information to add detail to the error.

It obvious that the transaction is not allowed to commit, but rollback only does not mean "no more selects". Why does WildFly enforce this?

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:272)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:2005)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:2020)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:869)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction.checkAutoCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:182)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction.<init>(JdbcTransaction.java:170)
... 67 more
```

In my opinion SQLException is used when something is wrong. Rollback-only is not wrong, it is just a flag, but a transaction is perfectly active. Yes, it has a restriction, so commit() should thrown an SQLException, but nothing else. So getAutoCommit should just return true or false here.

---

I feel this is a bug and created an issue.

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-18253